# Iterate over geojson in D3.js and return values when condition is met

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

In D3.js I'm attempting to iterate over a geojson file finding values for a specific attribute. For example, I want to iterate over the entire geojson file and if the value for the key `state` is equal to `KS`, return that piece of data.

I'm fairly new to D3 and I haven't found anything that would allow me to do that. My approach could be flawed, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [{
       "type": "Feature",
       "id": "KDDC",
       "state": "KS",
       "properties": {
          "name": "Dodge City Regional Airport",
          "address": "100 Airport Road, Dodge City, KS, United States"
       },
       "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
             -99.965556000000007,
             37.763333000000003
          ]
       }
   },
```

-- Begin Code --

```
d3.json("airports.json", function(collection) {

   var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(collection),
       path   = d3.geo.path().projection(project);

   path.pointRadius(5);

   var locations = g.selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features, function(d) {
         if(d.state == "KS"){
            console.log(d.state);
            return d.state;
         }
      })
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("opacity", 100);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the returned data? If you only want to extract it, then using d3 is overkill. You can achieve the same thing with a simple javascript loop.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), before passing it into the data() method.

For example (your code was very close!)

```
var locations = g.selectAll("path")
  .data(collection.features.filter(function(d) {
     return d.state == "KS";
  })
  .enter()
  ...
```

Check the d3 API documentation on [Arrays](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays) - it does a great job of highlighting both d3.js array functionality AND built-in javascript array functionality that are commonly used.